# Subsetting by index rows not working in R?

Tags: r

I've done this thousands of times, but I know I'm missing something here. I want to subset a data frame I have by the columns that match up in another one. However, the standard process doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I have:

```
a <- as.character(df1$col1)
b <- names(df2)
df2[(b %in% a), ]
```

Now the final line doesn't appear to do anything. No errors, but the `b %in% a` bit certainly doesn't return all `TRUE`.

```
a[1:10]
"2.5D"             "2D"               "2DFighter"        "3DPlatformer"    "3DVision"         "4PlayerLocal"     "4X"               "Abstract"        "Action"           "Action-Adventure"

b[1:10]
"appid"            "2.5D"             "2D"               "4PlayerLocal"    "6DOF"             "Action"           "Action-Adventure" "ActionRPG"       "Adventure"        "Anime" 

b[1:10] %in% a[1:10]
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

names(df2[(b %in% a), ])
"appid"            "2.5D"             "2D"               "4PlayerLocal"    "6DOF"             "Action"           "Action-Adventure" "ActionRPG"       "Adventure"        "Anime"
```

What I want is df2 to be subset by the matching columns in df1. I want to say this is the right approach, as I even have both the vectors that I'm matching with `%in%` are both the same character format. Yet the columnar subset appears to not be doing anything.

Is there anything immediately obvious as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you probably just subset `df2` with `df2[as.character(df1$col1),]`? I think the `%in%` test is superfluous, as long as you're filtering on row names.

Comment: The "comma" in the `names(df2[(b %in% a) , ])` is giving you **all** of the vector returned from `names()`.

Comment: Maybe try `df2[ ,(b %in% a) ]` instead of `df2[(b %in% a), ]`? Note the comma difference, meaning you're subsetting columns instead of rows.

Comment: Thanks @rosscova that did the trick!

Comment: Great! I've turned it into a brief answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's important here is that when subsetting using `df[a,b]`, the `a` subsets rows, and the `b` subsets columns.

This(as mentioned by @Kevin in the comments):

```
df2[(b %in% a), ]
```

is subsetting some rows out of the data frame, meaning all columns are still present. To subset columns instead, we need:

```
df2[ ,(b %in% a) ]
```